# is the converse true

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that a sequence {s$_n$}  of positive numbers satisﬁes
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=0 $$

Show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1s_n =\infty $$  Is the converse true?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: The proof should be one line. Use the fact that the sequence is **positive**. With some manipulation, the proof shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The result isn't true in the general case: take the counterexample:
$$s_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
but true for a positive (or negative) sequence.

Comment: $(s_n)$ has to be a positive sequence

Answer (score 1):

Let $c > 0$. There is an $n_0$ such that for $n \ge n_0$ we have $0 < s_n < \frac 1 c$, which implies $\frac 1{s_n} > c$. That means $\lim \frac1{s_n} = \infty$.

You can basically reverse the proof to show that $s_n < \varepsilon$ if $\frac 1{s_n} > \frac 1{\varepsilon}$, so the converse is true. In fact, the converse even holds if not all $s_n$ are positive.